# Добавление папки в jar архив

Tags: python, jar

Мне нужно через python скрипт упаковывать в уже существующий jar архив папку с файлами. Как это реализовать?

Реализовать это нужно без пересборки и компиляции проекта, как это делают архиваторы, поддерживающие работу с jar файлами как с архивами.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего это сделать, пересобирая весь архив с нуля, с помощью вызова из Python'а внешних программ  - связки javac+jar.
Первая - скомпилирует все классы в байткод, вторая - аккуратно упакует скомпилированное дерево в JAR'ник, создав при этом и **все необходимые подписи** в META-INF/ файлов-классов.

1) Компиляция:

```
javac -d ./output_dir *.java
```

2) Билд:

```
jar cf JAR.jar ./output_dir/*
```

Comment: Нужно именно как-нибудь упаковать, так как есть только jar файл. Без исходников.

Comment: Что мешает вытащить из жарника все скомпилиоованные классы и переупаковать их?